# I need to know the visa requirement in Miami and Madrid

Tags: visas

I am travelling to costa Rica and would have stopover in Madrid and Miami,do I need a visa with any of those countries?I'm a Philippine passport holder

Comment: Have you looked up *entry requirements for philippines citizens*? Otherwise, they are completely separate questions. Also please clarify if you intend to leave the airports or not.

Comment: As far as I know Visa is not required for Filipinos in entering Costa Rica for a short visit, but passing through Miami might be a problem for me as they might require me to have a transit visa, not so sure anyone can answer please

Answer (score 1):

Madrid is in Spain, in the Schengen zone of the European Union.  A visa is not required for Philippine citizens if you have an immediate connecting flight leaving Schengen from the same airport.

However, Miami is in the United States and a **visa is required** for Philippine citizens.  Unlike most of the world, the US does not recognize the concept of sterile transit, meaning everybody has to pass through Immigration.

Comment: "if you have an immediate connecting flight from the same airport": actually, the requirement is *if you can make your connection without passing through passport control.*  Also, I don't know what you mean by "which the US does not really recognize."  The US certainly recognizes transit, and even has a visa category just for transit, the C visa.

Comment: @phoog The US doesn't recognise *sterile* transit: even int'l-int'l transit pax must go through immigration.